# Mongoose prevent assignment of default value to enum

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

I have the following property in object defined in Mongoose schema, is there a way to prevent Moongose from assigning default enum value on `App.create()` or during upserting

```
band_collection: {
    type: String,
    enum: COLLECTIONS.concat('Custom')
}

// collection

COLLECTIONS = ['red', 'white', 'blue']
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm nope that shouldn't be happening, that code looks correct as far as I can tell. Can you provide a more complete code sample?